# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: window.setTimeout(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, google-tag-manager

I have wrapped a Javascript function in setTimeout() and I'm running this code on a site via Google Tag Manager. It works - there is a 3000 millisecond delay before the code executes and it has solved a problem for me.

However, when I go into the Javascript console on google chrome, I see `Uncaught TypeError: window.setTimeout(...) is not a function` for every time this function executes.

Below is a minimised version of my code:

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {

    function eventHandler(e) {
        //Code here
    }

        //Code here
        item[i].addEventListener("event", eventHandler, false);

    }
}, 3000)();
</script>
```

Any ideas why it's throwing this error or how it can be fixed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove the `()` at the very end (you're trying to call the return value of setTimeout() as if it's a function, but afaik it's a number) ((this is also why you're seeing "window.setTimeout(…) is not a function", as opposed to "window.setTimeout is not a function"))

Comment: @ChrisG you made my day XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically it's because `window.setTimeout` returns an identifier number and doesn't return a function, so replace your `window.setTimeout` call with:

```
<script>
var id = window.setTimeout(function() {

    function eventHandler(e) {
        //Code here
    }

        //Code here
        item[i].addEventListener("event", eventHandler, false);

    }
}, 3000);
</script>
```